# P4: can add files but cannot submit them

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to add a library to my project and commit it to perforce, but some files cannot be submitted.  I can mark the files for add and that works fine, but when I try to submit I get several errors similar to this:

```
open for write: mr/trunk/program/unitybranch/mr_unity5_0506/assets/ktplay/editor/xuporter
/mods/plugins/snsplugins/ktplaypluginweibo/weibo_sdk_3.1.3/weibosdk.bundle/images
/timeline_relationship_icon_addattention%403x.png,d\t6056t842881.tmp: The system cannot 
find the path specified.

Submit aborted -- fix problems then use 'p4 submit -c 30175'.

Some file(s) could not be transferred from client.
```

I've checked and rechecked and the files definitely exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out we were hitting the path length limit in Windows with some of the files. There's a Knowledge Base article about it here with some potential solutions:

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3051

For us the solution was to move the entire project to cut around 20 characters from the base path.